# "gem list" returns non-empty after uninstalling gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to completely clean up my ruby environment, because my gem install is failing to do anything.
So I did:

```
sudo gem uninstall -aIx
```

But following that:

```
gem list
```

still returns a long list of gems. Why?

Is there way to get rid of everything and start from scratch?

Comment: `sudo gem` is not the same as `gem`. This is because the shell looks up the `gem` command through `PATH`, and `PATH` is different for `root` than for your user. Therefore `sudo gem` runs another version of Ruby than `gem` without `sudo`. You can verify this yourself. Run `gem env` and then `sudo gem env`, and you will see they are not the same. You should not use `sudo` if you installed your Ruby with RVM or another Ruby manager.

Comment: @Casper +1 for a good catch, although I suspect *GEM_HOME* and *RUBY_ROOT* are the same for this user simply because the OP is presumably relying on the system Ruby. While I think my answer solves for the broader use case, [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075858/gem-list-returns-non-empty-after-uninstalling-gems/72077233?noredirect=1#comment127354142_72075858) is a great point for people who *have* properly configured a version manager but are seeing different gem sets.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Thanks. I suspected he has two versions installed, because `gem list` shows gems are still present even after he nuked his whole environment. But I never tried `gem uninstall -a`, so not sure if it actually deletes everything. Let's see if OP returns with some more info on this. I find in 90% of cases like this, the user doesn't realize he actually has two Ruby environments. Someone should write a FAQ about how `sudo` actully works in cases like this :-/ I see the same mistake here over and over.

Answer (score 2):

### You Should Never Have Zero Gems

First of all, installing gems as root into your system environment is always a bad idea. Secondly, uninstalling the system Ruby or its gems can often cause cause problems. **If you've wrecked your system Ruby, you may need to reinstall the core packages for it if you're on Linux, or do a system recovery if you're on macOS.** In future, always use a Ruby version manager to install Rubies and gems as a user rather than as root.

However, it's worth noting that *all* Ruby installations come with a set of default gems, most of which are for standard library modules or required for Ruby to run on your particular OS. Even a freshly-installed Ruby has a number of default gems, so you should never see a completely empty gem list unless you've broken your Ruby installation. For example, a fresh install of [JRuby](https://www.jruby.org/) 9.3.4.0 has 39 gems, 38 of which are prefixed with `default:`.

---

*NB: For whatever reason, xmlrpc is installed by default with JRuby on macOS, but is not locked to a default version. Nevertheless, for the purposes of this discussion you can consider it a default gem since it's installed as part of the base installation for the given Ruby.**

---

For example, given a fresh installation of JRuby, you can see the list of gems it installs by default:

```
$ gem list -l

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.2.29)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
csv (default: 3.1.2)
did_you_mean (1.3.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
ffi (default: 1.15.4 java)
fileutils (default: 1.4.1)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
io-console (default: 0.5.9 java)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
jar-dependencies (default: 0.4.1)
jruby-openssl (default: 0.12.2 java)
jruby-readline (default: 1.3.7 java)
json (default: 2.5.1 java)
logger (default: 1.5.1)
matrix (default: 0.3.0)
minitest (5.11.3)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
ostruct (default: 0.5.1)
power_assert (1.1.3)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.3.2 java)
racc (default: 1.5.2 java)
rake (12.3.3)
rake-ant (default: 1.0.4)
rdoc (default: 6.1.2.1)
rexml (default: 3.1.9.1)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
rubygems-update (default: 3.2.29)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
shell (default: 0.7)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
test-unit (3.2.9)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
webrick (default: 1.7.0)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
```

You should never try to get rid of default gems (e.g. any gem with a version prefixed with `default:`) because the installed Ruby version depends on them. That's why Ruby version managers typically define a separate *GEM_HOME* environment variable: so that you can add, upgrade, or remove gems other than the defaults without affecting the base installation. As this will generally result in having multiple versions of a given gem even if you run `gem clean`, using [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) or a version manager with [gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) can be useful.

If you've already borked your system Ruby, reinstall it as appropriate depending on your OS. Then install [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), or [rvm](https://rvm.io/), and use that to manage your Rubies and gems without modifying your system Ruby, and never ever run `sudo gem` again. You'll save yourself a lot of grief in the long run that way.

Comment: This idea that `sudo` is a magic wand that you just wave whenever you have a problem and it magically fixes it, is incredibly annoying, incredibly dangerous, and yet, so widely communicated. I really cannot understand why someone would teach something like that, but you see it all the time in answers and comments here on SO, SU, Unix.SE, Ask Ubuntu, Ask Different, and unfortunately even SF, and of course all over the web, on mailing lists, etc.

Comment: One of my favorite gems is [killergem](https://github.com/wmorgan/killergem) - it does nothing except troll the user with `$stderr.puts "deleting all files in /..."` if extconfig is run as sudo.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I agree with you, and specifically noted that the OP shouldn't have been using root privileges to change the system gems. However, while Ruby is not alone in needing a version manager to manage multiple versions or engines, other language ecosystems make it harder to bork the main system installation, and a lot clearer to new users how to manage multiple versions or add packages without affecting the OS-installed version. This is IMHO something that needs better documentation, or a standardized (but swappable) version manager installed by default. Just my $0.02.